# Find dimensions of an image in inches using OpenCV library

Tags: c++, opencv

Through my code, I want to know the dimensions of an image in inches. Via OpenCV, I can find the height and width of the array of pixels of the image using the following code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cv.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
     IplImage *img = cvLoadImage("photo.jpg");
     if (!img) {
        printf("Error: Couldn't open the image file.\n");
        return 1;
     }
     cout<<"Number of pixels in width = "<<img->width<<endl<<"Number of pixels in height = "<<img->height;
      return(0);
}
```

Please help me find the size of image in inches.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: You would need a means to get the pixel size from the hardware. I don't think OpenCV provides a means to get this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the DPI of your display. For that, you'll need to look into your platform's SDK (Windows/Linux/Mac) to learn how to retrieve this info since OpenCV doesn't provide a feature for this.

[Image Size Calculator](http://auctionrepair.com/pixels.html) is a JavaScript calculator that performs this calc. Check the source code of the page for the code.

Answer (score 0):

You must define px/inch ratio. And you will get value.

If you want to size of image in inches on your monitor take monitor resolution and size and you will get those ratio.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. If I take a picture of the moon, the moons diameter may well be 127 pixels. How many inches should that be? The moon is shining through a tree in that picture, and the tree is 341 pixels wide. How many inches is the tree? Really??

Comment: You can do it by calibrating acquisition system and calculating px/mm ratio. It's often used for gauging in industrial vision systems.

Comment: @krzych: That works under the assumption of a single imaged plane at sufficient distance from the camera. The moon/tree example shows what happens if objects aren't in the same plane.

Comment: Yes of course. I've forgotten to add this asumption to my comment.

Comment: @MSalters -1 Photos have DPI information, so it the size of image can be found.

Comment: @banuj: That's not factual, unless the image was obtained by scanning a physical photo. If I take a single picture with a camera and print that same picture twice, on A4 and A5 size, then the DPI of the two *prints* will differ by `sqrt(2)`. So what's the DPI of the picture from the camera? Is that based on the CCD size?